# Bash: awk removing parentheses from array items

Tags: bash, awk, grep, format, ip

So I'm creating a small network scan automation tool using nmap as part of the backend, when attempting to get hostnames and IP addresses the IP is formatted like this "(192.168.0.1)" currently I'm using this bit of code to grab hostname and IP and print.

```
devices=($( nmap $net_addr -sn | grep -E '([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})' | awk {' print $5 "\t" $6)'} ))

printf '%-10s %s\n' "${devices[@]}"
```

This code will print this

```
UNKNOWN (192.168.0.1)
UNKNOWN (192.168.0.3)
UNKNOWN (192.168.0.5)
UNKNOWN (192.168.0.6)
UNKNOWN (192.168.0.16)
UNKNOWN (192.168.0.18)
UNKNOWN (192.168.0.19)
UNKNOWN (192.168.0.21)
UNKNOWN (192.168.0.22)
UNKNOWN (192.168.0.23)
UNKNOWN (192.168.0.32)
UNKNOWN (192.168.0.253)
```

I attempted to use substr($6,2) but this only chops off the first bit and sadly as the nmap IP addresses are variable in length this doesn't help me.
In short, this is the desired output.

```
UNKNOWN 192.168.0.1
UNKNOWN 192.168.0.3
UNKNOWN 192.168.0.5
UNKNOWN 192.168.0.6
UNKNOWN 192.168.0.16
UNKNOWN 192.168.0.18
UNKNOWN 192.168.0.19
UNKNOWN 192.168.0.21
UNKNOWN 192.168.0.22
UNKNOWN 192.168.0.23
UNKNOWN 192.168.0.32
UNKNOWN 192.168.0.253
```

here is the output of nmap 192.168.0.0/24 -sn

```
Starting Nmap 7.40 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-12-31 14:42 UTC
Nmap scan report for UNKNOWN (192.168.0.1)
Host is up (0.0014s latency).
Nmap scan report for UNKNOWN (192.168.0.3)
Host is up (0.052s latency).
Nmap scan report for UNKNOWN (192.168.0.5)
Host is up (0.0065s latency).
Nmap scan report for UNKNOWN (192.168.0.6)
Host is up (0.0073s latency).
Nmap scan report for UNKNOWN (192.168.0.7)
Host is up (0.029s latency).
Nmap scan report for UNKNOWN (192.168.0.16)
Host is up (0.011s latency).
Nmap scan report for UNKNOWN (192.168.0.18)
Host is up (0.053s latency).
Nmap scan report for UNKNOWN (192.168.0.21)
Host is up (0.011s latency).
Nmap scan report for UNKNOWN (192.168.0.22)
Host is up (0.012s latency).
Nmap scan report for UNKNOWN (192.168.0.23)
Host is up (0.0061s latency).
Nmap scan report for UNKNOWN (192.168.0.32)
Host is up (0.0013s latency).
Nmap scan report for UNKNOWN (192.168.0.253)
Host is up (0.0011s latency).
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (12 hosts up) scanned in 3.16 seconds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your shown Input you could try following single `awk` to get the shown expected output.

```
your_command | awk '/Nmap scan report/{gsub(/\)|\(/,"",$NF);print $(NF-1),$NF}'
```

***EDIT:*** Eliminating `grep` from OP's command and trying to solve it within single `awk` itself now.

```
devices=$(nmap $net_addr -sn | awk --re-interval '{if(match($0,/\([0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\)/)){gsub(/\)|\(/,"",$NF);print $(NF-1),$NF}}')
```

Also since my `awk` is OLD one in case you have latest version of `awk` then kindly don't use `--re-interval` in solution.

Comment: ah ok so I've just run this: devices=($( nmap $net_addr -sn | grep -E '([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})' |  awk '/Nmap scan report/{gsub(/\)|\(/,"",$NF); print $(NF-1),$NF} )) and what I got out of it was this: ./program.sh: line 10: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
./program.sh: line 12: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: Just realised my issue haha, I missed off a quote mark, the code works like a charm thank you!

Comment: You don't need grep when you're using awk since awk can do anything useful that grep can do, for example: `grep 'foo' | awk '/bar/'` = `awk '/foo/ && /bar/'`.

Comment: I'll probably take that into consideration with my code thanks currently it's a bit of a bodge job

Comment: @user3019354, please try once my EDIT command and let me know if that helps, yes Ed sir is right we could match with regex and all within single `awk`, let me know how it goes as I haven't tested it, cheers !!

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 just tried it got this back "awk: not an option: --re-interval"

Comment: You probably don't need the `--re-interval` - that's only for a very old version of gawk, it's not needed with gawk versions that have come out in the past 5 years or so, nor will POSIX awks need/accept it.

Comment: @EdMorton, apologies Ed sir, I have very old version of `awk` I forgot to tell that if OP has new version of it no need to add `--re-interval` then, will add note now.

Comment: @user3019354, try without `--re-interval` and let us know how it goes then?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 ok I've corrected it and the command doesn't seem to be matching anything, the output is blank.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Yeah, the nmap output is the same... strange. I'll give it an experiment and get back to you!

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Got it working, in the end, I think the regex was matching wrong, not sure why maybe it was an error on my end. I also changed the regex back to [0-9]{1,3} in the first two as it makes the code more flexible even if it's not entirely necessary. been a great help thanks!

Comment: @user3019354, I got it, may be your output's last field IPs may not have 3 digits in first 2 fields, good catch. Cheers, enjoy learning and enjoy posting :)

Comment: FWIW `'{if(match($0,/\([0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\)/)){gsub(/\)|\(/,"",$NF);print $(NF-1),$NF}}'` = `'/\([0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\)/{gsub(/[()]/,"",$NF);print $(NF-1),$NF}'`. There's no need to put the condition inside the action and then test it with `if` and add brackets...

Answer (score 1):

You can try this sed too

```
nmap $net_addr -sn | sed '/^Nmap scan report for /!d;s///;s/[)(]//g'
```